# JQueryUI slider instead of number input type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a simple View in MVC3, with three inputs of type number. What I need to do is display a JQueryUI slider instead of input. I tried like this, but it only changes the shape of input form and there is no slider.

Code:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(".nmbr").slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 1,
                max: 100,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("input[name=" + $(this).attr("id") + "_value]").val(ui.value);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

And html:

```
<div>
<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_value" style="border:0;" />
<input type="number" class="nmbr" id="first" />
<br />
<br />

<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="second_value" style="border:0;" />
<input type="number" class="nmbr" id="second" />
<br />
<br />

<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="third_value" style="border:0;" />
<input type="number" class="nmbr" id="third" />
<br />
<br />
```

Where did I go off the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery UI's Slider`](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) uses `div` not `input` *(easy mistake to make)*.

Make the following changes:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
    $(".nmbr").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("input[name=" + $(this).attr("id") + "_value]").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_value" style="border:0;" />
<div class="nmbr" id="first"></div>
<br />
<br />

<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="second_value" style="border:0;" />
<div class="nmbr" class="nmbr" id="second"></div>
<br />
<br />

<label for="number">Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="third_value" style="border:0;" />
<div class="nmbr" class="nmbr" id="third"></div>
<br />
<br />
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/qN59g/5/

Comment: Works great. Maybe one more thing. How could I use a @Html.TextBox() element instead of <input type="text"> to show the values?

Comment: @UrošPodrekar I am terribly sorry, I have not used `mvc3` :-/

Comment: @Dom where is the `CSS` of slider? `CSS` field is empty in ur `jsfiddle` demo. but it displaying sliders well.

Comment: @Bishan in jsfiddle, when you use jqueryUI, a request is made to get the base theme file: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css